# How to hide blogger post form home page

Tags: blogger, posts

I have a website in which i don't want the posts to show on my homepage only the viewers can view the post by link so how can i do it . ihave tried redirecting my page but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your blog it's on Wordpress platform, you can use a password on post.
If it's on blogspot, this is not possible. This platform doesn't allow that.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way via Blogger to do that. Posts on homepage will load for sure.

But you can use CSS to make your post lists blan, like by using display:none; property.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'> 
<!-- only homepage -->
<style>
body{display:none;}
</style>
</b:if>
```

Something like above you can do. If you want to adjust other elements on your homepage, add css in the above style tag.